# Am I allowing some selection bias or is there a high correllation between using real looking names as aliases and good answers?

Tags: discussion

It just seems that I have found that people using "First Name" "Last Name" as their alias seem to give more reliable answers.  Possible bias is relatively smaller sample size than many of you here and my choice of alias.

Has anyone else seen similar correlations?

EDIT: Added *looking* to the question for clarity, added body question

*(Note: I am not implying thatt people without name looking aliases don't have quality answers, just that there has been a noticeable number of good answers I have seen that happen to be by people with name looking aliases)*

Comment: 1)  Correlation does not imply causation.  2)  I would hope that people choose to upvote questions based on their helpfulness, not because they chose to avoid a pseudonym online.

Comment: How do you know that Jon Skeet is a real name?

Comment: And you know this is their real name, because...?

Comment: I never said it was **their** real name and I qualified it in the body as first, last.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But you haven't shown us any of that statistical observational evidence. We love numbers and we want to see them.

Comment: I'll copy the link here, since my answer has been buried. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76539/206222) answer might be useful.;

Comment: @Mystical - I admitted my sample size was small (limited to the posts I've participated in).  And I have no problem with people saying, no that was just random initial clumping, we have found that there is no correlation.  I am honestly intersted in whether it is a general observation or if I was fooled by randomness.

Comment: @Emrakul can you do the same analysis on DisplayName like "% %"? (intent is that name has a space) - I would be curious

Comment: @Makoto He suggested neither (1) nor (2).

Answer (score 5):

### Executive Summary

I can see three big potential reasons this could fail:

1. You can't distinguish when someone attached their name to an account
2. You don't know if a name is real or made up
3. Good luck uncorrelating the relationship between real name and high reputation

### People with good answers are more likely to attach their name to them.

So John Doe signs up anonymously. He gets his feet wet and asks a few questions, answers a few more. He starts getting some reputation and likes the feeling, so he starts answering more. All of a sudden, he realizes that he has over 5,000 reputation, and that he is proud of the content he has created. He changes his user name from `user123456` to `John Doe`.

How are you going to account for this scenario?

### People are biased toward usernames that *look* real.

Jane Smith decides that she really wants to get this reputation thing. She notices that a lot of the top users use their real names, and figures that people must see an answer as more reliable if it has a name attached. So Jane changes her username from `user234567` to `Mary Magdalene` and starts answering up a storm. People think that's a real name, and give the answers more upvotes as a result.

### Proxy for Reputation

High reputation users generally have better quality (in the sense of score) answers than lower reputation users. This is kind of tautological really. Since most people who use their real names likely have higher reputation, all a real name is serving as is an proxy for high reputation (which is the real source of quality questions).

Comment: Oh man, it looks like you're "Executive Summary"ing everything now

Comment: I was curious if there was a correlation, not if that correlation meant anything, but nice writeup +1

Comment: @random, think of it as a TL;DR with more respect for the reader's reasons for not reading the whole thing (and if you think it's bad on my meta posts, you should see [my answers on The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945/jmac?tab=answers).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that people avoid new users. Questions from users whose usernames match `user\d+` (e.g. `user2385294`) are more likely to be from new users.

However, this question has been asked before, and [the correlation isn't true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76539/206222). Users with registered and modified nicknames are not any more likely than other users to have higher question quality (estimated by upvotes). There may be some minor bias, however, in the total number of votes on an answer. It appears that users with registered nicknames tend to provide better answers.

However, once people have a username of choice, I highly doubt it makes any difference.

Comment: I am not sure of the relevance of "new users" vs users with aliases comparisons to real looking name aliases vs non real looking name aliases